How should I balance an experiment with two sets of conditions and not enough trials for every combination of those conditions?
I have a within-subject experiment that tests participants' memory. There are 80 trials, and in each trial, participants read 1 of 20 sentences. Then, they have to manipulate the sentence in 1 of 4 ways (A1, A2, A3, A4). They answer 1 question, either B1 or B2. I'm most interested in the differences in scores between A conditions on B2. I'm especially interested in A1 vs the rest, but all are important. This will be used as a manipulation check, as I expect A1 to be higher than the rest.
Would it be better to do:
a) 1 B question per sentence, for all 4 trials, so that I can compare all A conditions for those 10 sentences that had the B2 question?
b) Each sentence has 2 B1 trials and 2 B2 trials, so I can compare 2 A conditions for all 20 sentences?
There are some limitations:
I can't have 8 repetitions of each sentence, only 4.
B1 and B2 must be equally likely.
